# Is it possible to call TeamViewer.exe from a web page to remote connect to host and pass-thru password details?

Tags: angularjs, chrome-native-messaging, teamviewer

I was hoping to integrate a TeamViewer button into my Web Application that allowed my users to initiate a remote connection to a pre-defined host using their local instance of TeamViewer installed on each user's computer. However, this has proposed issues and seems a lot more complicated than I first anticipated.

I have attempted to call `https://start.teamviewer.com/device/<ID>/authorization/password/mode/control` from a URL and pass in the device id, which does in fact work (not seamlessly as it always opens up a new tab), however, the user is prompted everytime for their AD credentials, despite the fact that we have set pre-entered passwords on a lot of our hosts.  This therefore, is a time consuming solution and not really the ideal approach.

My other thought was to try and call the command `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe -i <ID> --Password <PASSWORD>` from some sort of chrome `NativeMessaging` extension, but I can't seem to get this working.

I have created my manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "com.mycompany.myapp",
  "description": "myapp",
  "path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Teamviewer\\TeamViewer.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://........cnlfdm/"
  ]
}
```

I have also created my registry entry to correspond to my manifest file above.

I then call from my onClick() function:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.mycompany.myapp');

port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
     console.log("Received" + msg);
});

port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
     console.log("Disconnected");
});

port.postMessage({ text: "Hello, my_application" });
```

Which gives me the error `Cannot read property 'sendNativeMessage' of undefined`.

Ultimately, I am trying to allow users to click on a button which launches a remote control session to a pre-defined host and pass-through the password details (or make use of the pre-entered password details).

I should mention that I am trying to call this from an `ng-click()` function within my AngularJS application, so I'm not sure if this is having some affect on the problem.

Comment: Did you get through this issue ?

Comment: Nope, couldn't resolve it and couldn't get any help from TeamViewer.  The fact that you can use TeamViewer's web portal to call a remote session without any user intervention means that it's possible, but I couldn't find any further information on how to call this from my own application.